# PHP can't set range(0, 2 million) -- memory error

Tags: php, memory

I need to set an array from 1 to 2 million for my current project.  The problem is that I get a memory error when I try to execute...

**Edit:**

This is for a ProjectEuler problem which I have already solved.  However, I am refactoring the code to do it much faster (original time was ~90 secs).

I'm using the sieve of eratosthenes to mark the primes from 0 to 2mil.  [Wikipedia article on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

**EndEdit**

```
<?php
range(0,2000000);
?>
```

obviously if this won't work, the rest of the code won't work.

Any ideas?

P.S. I tried `ini_set('memory', '30M');` , but that didn't work either.

**Edit**

Thanks to all who pointed out that the memory would need to be much larger than I first anticipated.  I solved the problem by throwing in `ini_set('memory_limit', '4000000000'); //about 3.73 gig`

**EndFinalEdit**

Comment: Let's start from the beginning, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need that big a range? What are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better way.

Comment: Don't know the quality of the source, but here http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2008/03/did_you_know_that_each_integer.html . Implying that it takes 68 bytes, which means you need way over 100mb for your array.

Comment: @Nanne

..thanks for the info..did not know that!

Comment: for prime test you need only `sqrt` of your length

Comment: @Rifat's suggestion is the right way to go, but consider just not using PHP for this type of problem `:)`

Comment: @Rifat , will that work for the sieve though?  I can post my original (90 second) solution that used the "loop over 0 to sqrt(2000000)" technique, but I wanted to try to implement the sieve

Comment: Run your solution file with `-d memory_limit=1G` parameter in console to have it 1Gb memory allowed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can set at arbitrary place and get data from arbitrary index there is no point of sequential array.

```
// completely acceptable in php
$data[2000000] = 2000000;
```

If you are solving this euler problem in console (what I usually do), **then run the php file with `-d memory_limit=4G` parameter**. It'll run with 4 GB of memory.

```
php -d memory_limit=4G /path/to/euler/problem.php
```

---

BTW You can create some magic class which can mimic that you have a big array like that. :)

```
class MySuperCoolLongIntArray{
    private $data=array();
    public get_int($index){
        return isset($this->data[$index])? $this->data[$index]: 0;
    }
    public set_int($index, $value){
        $this->data[$index]=$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the console set up to run java, but thanks for the suggestion. Also, I enjoy your humorous tone XD .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the php.ini file.

There is a setting `memory_limit` - that is probably stopping you doing this ridiculous range.

Answer (score 0):

You will need more than 160M memory for range(0, 2000000) and half this will be anough for range(1000000, 2000000).

From php.ini:

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 256M